# Groovy simple function with array

Tags: arrays, function, groovy

I recently started learning Groovy.
I don't know best way to write simple function in Groovy:
Function must multiply every element in array by 2, if it's positive, and divide by 3, if it's negative. I wrote some java's like code:

`def array = [5,-8,1,4,7,3,-2,-10,5,0,4]`

```
public void fun(){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size; i++){
        if(array[i] > 0) array[i] = array[i] * 2;
        else array[i] = array[i] / 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def array = [5,-8,1,4,7,3,-2,-10,5,0,4].collect { it > 0 ? it * 2 : it / 3 }
```

Or if you want to split it into two lines:

```
def array = [5,-8,1,4,7,3,-2,-10,5,0,4]
array = array.collect { it > 0 ? it * 2 : it / 3 }
```

You can find the documentation for the `collect` method [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)). You might also want to read up on [closures](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Robby Cornelissen's approach with `collect` which will create new array. But if you would like to modify your original array (like in your current code) you can write it like below:

```
array.eachWithIndex { it, index -> 
    array[index] = it > 0 ? it * 2 : it / 3
}
```